# Require module from a root path

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I've these directories:

```
'C:\\src' // Root path.
'C:\\src\\inner1' // Contain 'a.js'
'C:\\src\\inner2\\innermost' // Contain 'b.js'
```

So, if I do this in `C:\\src\\inner1\\a.js`:

```
require('inner2/innermost/b')
```

It must return the exported value from `C:\\src\\inner2\\innermost\\b.js`, but I do not want to use the executing script relative path, e.g.:

```
require('../inner2/innermost/b')
```

So, independently of the current script directory, I want to require a module from such root path.

How can I do it? There is no problem if I need to specify something at `package.json`.

Comment: Take a look https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: @GeorgiyDubrov Interesting, but `__dirname` is not a fixed directory, it is different depending on the directory.

Comment: @matt you missed the GLOBAL part. In the root .js file that starts everything you would use dirname but set it as a GLOBAL variable that can be passed on to sub .js files.

Comment: @Darkrum Yes, entry file. Though Node.js warns `GLOBAL` is deprecated, and there's probably no way to globalize something between files, as dat would do a mess.

Comment: What's your objective? Relative paths are much more stable and cause less problems than root-relative paths which was why node.js supports relative path and NOT support root-relative paths. `I really need this` is not an objective. Sounds like an a/b problem to me

Comment: @slebetman It is not a problem, but gets messy, as soon I nest directories and want to directly require far modules. For example, `../../../utils/blah`, that's a messy require path for me.

Comment: Then the solution is to write an install script to copy common modules to `node_modules`. Then you can just `require('blah')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
path = require('path');
path.resolve('../inner2/mostinner/b');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does the same as the example of what I did not want, but thanks for trying to help :).

Comment: @Matt what OS you are using? tested on windows, works exactly the same way you want it

Comment: Yes, it works; but it is not using path relative to root (`C:\\src`). I want to directly require from this `C:\\src` path, e.g.: `require('inner2/mostinner/b')`, I already said about your example in my question.